# c++. Зачем нужны динамические переменные? Понятно что их можно удалять если не нужны и освобождается память в ОЗУ, но я не понимаю

Tags: c++, указатели

Можно ли в эти переменные вставлять свои/пользовательские значения? Или это ТОЛЬКО адрес ячейки? Чем плохи статические переменные?
Понятно что при помощи указателей выделяется память для переменной, то есть по сути в указатель нельзя вставить свое/пользовательское значение, так как он выделяет? а когда удаляется память для переменной удаляется ли переменная со своим значением?
c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли в эти переменные вставлять свои/пользовательские значения?

В сами переменные-указатели — адрес, а в ячейки, на которые он указывает — нужно :), иначе к чему это всё? Надо только корректно выделить память.

> Или это ТОЛЬКО адрес ячейки?

```
int * p = new int;
```

В переменной `p` только адрес. Но по этому адресу можно записывать данные

```
*p = 1024;
```

> Чем плохи статические переменные?

Ну, например, в стеке столько места может не быть. Потом, время жизни локальных переменных ограничено временем жизни функции. Есть и другие варианты использования — например, тот же вектор с динамически растущим размером, или список, собранный через указатели...

> Понятно что при помощи указателей выделяется память для переменной, то есть по сути в указатель нельзя вставить свое/пользовательское значение, так как он выделяет?

Выделение памяти в С++ выполняется с помощью оператора `new`, освобождение — с помощью оператора `delete`.

> а когда удаляется память для переменной удаляется ли переменная со своим значением?

Память освобождается, т.е. что в ней после этого находится — это уже не ваше дело, вы не должны обращаться к памяти после ее освобождения.

Увы, это большая и, как ни странно, часто непонятная изучающим тема. Так что, боюсь, ответы просто добавят пищу для новых вопросов.

Comment: @enterproggramming могу добавить к ответу то, что динамические переменные используются для тех случаев, когда вам нужно создать какой-либо объект в памяти, а потом получать к нему доступ в каком-нибудь другом месте. Статические переменные не подходят для этого, потому что инициализировать их можно лишь один раз, при этом они живут на протяжении всей программы. Динамическое выделение памяти можно совершить в любом месте программы. Все, что вам нужно будет для доступа к выделенному объекту - это указатель на него. При помощи него можно будет оперировать с созданным экземпляром откуда угодно

Comment: @enterproggramming яркий пример - структура данных "список". Если вы просто сделаете структуру "узел" и в качестве одного из его переменных-членов сделаете стековую переменную другой ноды, то вы добьетесь лишь ошибки компиляции. Массив нод вы тоже сделать не можете, потому что иначе это будет не список, а массив (логично). Поэтому применяют динамическое выделение памяти. Где-то в куче создают объект ноды, а в предыдущей ноде сохраняют указатель на следующую. При этом доступ к данным следующей ноды осуществляют через указатель.

Comment: @enterproggramming и если совсем упрощать, то динамическое выделение памяти крайне полезно в тех случаях, где вам нужно иметь доступ к объекту вне области видимости, в которой он был создан